# Click detection on document's added element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using currently on my page script which one of it's elements is adding and clicking on different elements like text, divs and images.

At the beginning everything is hide using jQuery hide method and only one input is shown. If everytjing is correct then the rest is shown - and now you can add new elements. In my html documentI am using method which looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
          hideUnused();
          $('#file_upload').uploadify({
            //all stuff from uploadify <- not important now
          })
          document.onclick = function (evt) {
            ClickDocument(evt); //<- important now
           };})
```

And it works great for everything that is on page at the beginning, but when I am adding new elements (simply append child method) it looks like they are out of the DOM tree which ClickDocument method sees.

And it is ClickDocument method:

```
function ClickDocument(e){
    e = e || event;   
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    alert(target.nodeName);
    return;
}
```

It is extremly simple to test it only.
So does anyone have got any idea what I can do with it?

Oh I've forgot to mentioned one thing - I've been testing live events http://api.jquery.com/live/ but it doesn't fit to my expectations. It doesn't work with show/hide methods.

Thank you very much for attention and help.

**EDIT:**

As I've been sugested I've used `.delegate()` method in two different ways. Both changed the old html code from 
`$(document).ready(function()`
into
`$("body").delegate(".kElement","click", function(evt){` as my class elements that I want to have extra actions on click is kElement.
So The first one looks like that:

```
$("body").delegate(".kElement","click", function(evt){
               e = evt || event;   
                var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
                alert(target.nodeName);

           })
```

and the second looks like that:

```
$("body").delegate(".kElement","click", function(evt){
               ClickDocument(evt);                
           })
```

So it should show alert when I click on my object, but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Regarding your edit; you should still be wrapping the delegation code in a ``.ready()`` function if the code is being called before the ``<body>`` element

Comment: still it is in `.ready()` function.

Answer (score 2):

If you're adding elements to a page at a later date and require events to work then you will need to use event delegation. In simplified terms, this means attaching an event to the parent of a collection of elements, and then checking to see if any of the children have been clicked.

For example

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

I can attach events to all the child elements [using the .on() method in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$('.parent').on('click', '.child', function(event){
    // Do something here
})
```

The .on() and .off() methods are the newer and preferred way to handle events in jQuery (as you can assign normal events too) but should you be using an older version of jQuery then you will [need the delegate() method](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

Avoid using .live() as it doesn't perform as well as .delegate() and has issues with chaining (as well as being deprecated).

Comment: but still using this method I have got problem implementing my idea into app. I've edited my question to show what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

While attaching/binding your click events, use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead of `.bind()`

`.live()` will ensure, that the event will be applicable on all future elements too.

Comment: But as I said before if I add `.live()` than `show()` and `hide()` doesn't work.